# C# learning websites similar to javabat

Tags: c#

To those unfamiliar,  javabat is a website that hosts dozens of small java coding tasks.  You write an implementation, the site compiles the code, and you get immediate feedback on whether your answer was correct. In my opinion it's an excellent resource for those learning the language (and long-time java coders who want to keep their low-level skills sharp).

Is there anything similar to this in the C# world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check out [Compilr](http://compilr.com/):

> Compilr is a pet project created by
>   Kyle Hankinson. The idea has been
>   around for many years but the work
>   finally started in January 2007.
>   Compilr is the first online
>   development community allowing
>   developers to build and compile the
>   projects online, without the need of
>   downloading and installing a compiler
>   to their system. Being web based it is
>   completely OS independent meaning you
>   can build your favorite language from
>   Windows, Linux, OSX or any other
>   system with a compatible web browser.
>
> Currently I have been focusing Compilr
>   on C#.Net; however, as development
>   continues many other languages will be
>   added.

Also [MSDN Virtual Labs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa570323.aspx):

> Welcome to the MSDN Virtual Labs! Quickly evaluate or learn how to build great applications for Windows and the Web through a series of guided, hands-on labs which can be completed in 90 minutes or less. The best part is, the MSDN Virtual Labs don’t require any installation and are available to you immediately for FREE.

Also you could check out [CodeRun's IDE](http://www.coderun.com/ide/).

Comment: Thanks for that link to MSDN Virtual Labs! I can't believe I never knew about that.

Comment: I don't think this answer is still relevant. Compilr has been acquired by Lynda.com.

Answer (score 1):

http://java2s.com/ has a lot of C# examples and tutorials.
But, they also have a lot of ads and flash content which I don't always trust.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn with the help of an instructor check out below links. Remember these are paid classes and instructor will cover course in virtual classroom online.

[Programming in C# Specialist](http://www.wiziq.com/course/11243-mcsd-series-programming-in-c-specialist-exam-70-483)

[DOT NET Development](http://www.wiziq.com/course/10762-dot-net-development)